# clicking link based on input value

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I was wondering is there a way for me to click a link with button but i want to click the link based on an input value?

Sorry for bad English

```js
function clicklink() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("hud-link")[0].click();
}
```

```html
<div class="hud">
    <a class="hud-link" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link Here 1</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="hud">
    <a class="hud-link" href="https://google.com">Link Here 2</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="hud">
    <a class="hud-link" href="https://yahoo.com">Link Here 3</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="hud">
    <a class="hud-link" href="https://bing.com">Link Here 4</a>
</div>
<br>
<input type="number" min="0" max="4" value="0">

<button onclick="clicklink();">Click Link</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to first get both the button and the input elements as variables. Then you'll want to use the `.value` of your `input` as the index in your `.getElementsByClassName()` selector.

Also, you'll want to make use of [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) by adding an event listener to your button, through which you call your function.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
const input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("hud-link")[input.value].click();
});
```

```html
<div class="hud">
  <a class="hud-link" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Link Here 1</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="hud">
  <a class="hud-link" href="https://google.com">Link Here 2</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="hud">
  <a class="hud-link" href="https://yahoo.com">Link Here 3</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="hud">
  <a class="hud-link" href="https://bing.com">Link Here 4</a>
</div>
<br>
<input type="number" min="0" max="4" value="0">

<button>Click Link</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
function clicklink() {
var number = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  document.getElementsByClassName("hud-link")[number].click();
}
```